# How to differentiate selected, non selected section on segmented controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

I have used the following code to create a segmented controller, but I can't differentiate which is selected and which is not selected. How do I differentiate?

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;
segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
                [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Male" atIndex:0 animated:YES];
                [segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Female" atIndex:1 animated:YES];
                segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
                segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(100,10,200,30);
                [segmentedControl setMomentary:YES];
                [segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];



- (void)segmentSwitch:(id)sender 
{
    segmentedControl = (UISegmentedControl *) sender;
    NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    UIView *firstView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20,20)];
    firstView.backgroundColor=[UIColor greenColor];
    UIView *secondView =[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20,20)];
    firstView.backgroundColor=[UIColor brownColor];
    if (selectedSegment == 0) 
    {
        NSLog(@"first segment");
        //toggle the correct view to be visible
        strGender =[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Male"];
        [firstView setHidden:NO];
        [secondView setHidden:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"second segment");
        //toggle the correct view to be visible
        strGender =[[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"Female"];
        [firstView setHidden:YES];
        [secondView setHidden:NO];
    }
}
```

Comment: Where you are having problem in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;

segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];

segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 6, 320, 40);
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];

[segmentedControl setMomentary:YES];
[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

// here is the code how to differenciate selected , non selected section on segmented //controller

```
int selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

if(selectedSegment == 0)
{
 // code 1
}
else if(selectedSegment == 1)
{
 // code 2
}enter code here
```

Comment: thanx for ur reply,, i have tried ur code its not working,,when i click on a segment its colour should change(like how it happens in switch)

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here. Based on your comment to @Surjit's answer, you will have to use [`insertSegmentWithImage:atIndex:animated`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006807-CH3-SW20) if you want to change the color of the segment. You will need to have images for each segment for both selected and non-selected state.

But there are few problems in your `segmentSwitch:` method. You are creating both `firstView` and `secondView` but not adding them to the view hierarchy. You are setting the background color of `firstView` twice. You probably intended one of the calls to be to `secondView`. And there's no point changing the `hidden` property of the two views without them being on the screen. If you are looking to switch between two views of different colors, then declare them as ivars and initialize them elsewhere and then switch their `hidden` on segment switch.

Answer (score 0):

// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl;  // add this to your (.h) file

segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:nil];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Red" atIndex:0 animated:YES];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Green" atIndex:1 animated:YES];
[segmentedControl insertSegmentWithTitle:@"Blue" atIndex:2 animated:YES];
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBezeled;
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 40);
segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0;
segmentedControl.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
segmentedControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
[segmentedControl setMomentary:NO];   // imp property (change it & see magic)

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentSwitch:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
[self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

}

- (IBAction)segmentSwitch:(id)sender {
  NSInteger selectedSegment = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;

  if (selectedSegment == 0)
      self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
  else if (selectedSegment == 1)
      self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
  else if (selectedSegment == 2)
      self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
  }

Just copy & paste this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
see this example here i am setting tint color for selected
and unselected segment index.

But before that please unchecked the momentary state from xib 
for UISegmentedControl.


- (void)segmentAction:(id)sender{
UIColor *tintcolor1=[UIColor colorWithRed:204/255.0 green:204/255.0 blue:204/255.0 alpha:1.0];
UIColor *tintcolor2=[UIColor colorWithRed:211/255.0 green:78/255.0 blue:65/255.0 alpha:1.0];

for (int i=0; i<[segment_controller.subviews count]; i++) 
{

    if ([[segment_controller.subviews objectAtIndex:i]isSelected] ) 
    {               

        [[segment_controller.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor2];
    }else
    {

        [[segment_controller.subviews objectAtIndex:i] setTintColor:tintcolor1];
    }


}
```